# Calculating the expectation value of an observable over a finite region rather than an an entire distribution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, wavefunction

Given an operator $\hat{Q}(x)$, the expectation value of the observable $\langle Q \rangle$ is calculated by integrating the probability distribution over the entire space as

\begin{equation}
\langle Q \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi^{*}(x) \hat{Q}(x) \psi(x) dx
\end{equation}

Is it possible to calculate the expectation value $\langle Q \rangle_{ab}$ over just a finite range $x \in [a,b]$ such that

\begin{equation}
\langle Q \rangle_{ab} = \int_{a}^{b} \psi^{*}(x) \hat{Q}(x) \psi(x) dx.
\end{equation}

It would seem that the answer is yes. For example, a detector in the lab usually takes measurements only in a finite space rather than over an infinite space. Furthermore, as as example, it seems that for a piece-wise potential that gives three separate wave functions $\psi_{1}(x), \psi_{2}(x) \text{ and } \psi_{3}(x)$, the above calculation would be performed due to

\begin{equation}
\langle Q \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{a} \psi_{1}^{*}(x) \hat{Q}(x) \psi_{1}(x) dx + \int_{a}^{b} \psi_{2}^{*}(x) \hat{Q}(x) \psi_{2}(x) dx + \int_{b}^{\infty} \psi_{3}^{*}(x) \hat{Q}(x) \psi_{3}(x) dx.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

The first question has positive answer. The second one has again positive answer if $Q$ preserves pairwise orthogonality of the three functions $\psi_j$. Roughly speaking, it happens if $Q$ commutes with the position operator.

Answer (score 0):

The below seems to long to add as a comment, so, just trying to mathematically formalize the @Valter Moretti 's answer, namely, there is a useful approach consisting using Heaviside function. Precisely, the piece-wise your wave function is
\begin{equation}
 \psi(x) = \psi_1(x) H(a-x) + \psi_2 ( H(x-a) + H(x-b)) + \psi_3 H(x-b)
\end{equation}
when calculating the expected value of $\hat{Q}$, it is seen that:

\begin{align}
 &\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi(x)  \hat{Q} \psi(x) \mathrm{d} x  = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\psi_1(x) H(a-x) + \psi_2 ( H(x-a) + H(x-b)) + \psi_3 H(x-b) \right) \hat{Q} \psi(x) \mathrm{d} x = \\
 & = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi_1(x) H(a-x)  \hat{Q} \psi(x) \mathrm{d} x +  \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi_2 ( H(x-a) + H(x-b)) \hat{Q} \psi(x) \mathrm{d} x \\ 
 & + \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi_3 H(x-b) \hat{Q} \psi(x) \mathrm{d} x = \\
 & = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{a} \psi_1(x)  \hat{Q} \psi(x) \mathrm{d} x +  \int\limits_{a}^{b} \psi_2  \hat{Q} \psi(x) \mathrm{d} x + \int\limits_{b}^{\infty} \psi_3 \hat{Q} \psi(x) \mathrm{d} x
\end{align}
Next, the $\hat{Q}$ operates somehow on the Heaviside function so if the function on the right commutes with  the operator you can write the equation at the end of the question.